# using regex with find

Tags: bash, find

Let's say I need to find all files in `/var/log/` except `btmp`, `lastlog`, `wtmp`. And I only need depth 1. I tried with the following `find` command, but that does not work as expected:

```
find /var/log/ -maxdepth 1 -type f \! -name '(btmp|lastlog|wtmp)'
```

Comment: `-name` arguments are interpreted as shell glob patterns, not a regex.  You need `-regex` if your `find` supports it: check your manpage.  That's a really odd set of `find` parameters, by the way.  You could accomplish the same with `bash`'s `-extglob` feature, as in `/var/log/!(btmp|lastlog|wtmp)` (still a glob, not a regex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should accomplish what you want:

```
find /var/log/ -maxdepth 1 -type f \! -regex '/var/log/\(btmp\|lastlog\|wtmp\)' -exec ls {} \;
```

Answer (score 3):

`-name` doesn't take a regex, it takes a literal name, potentially with globs. You can either use `-regex` instead (possibly a gnu extension?) or add the three separately

```
find ... \! -name btmp \! -name lastlog \! -name wtmp
```

Or you can skip `find` entirely and use bash's extended globbing.

```
shopt -s extglob
echo !(btmp|lastlog|wtmp)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do it:

```
ls -1 /var/log/ | grep -v 'btmp\|lastlog\|wtmp'
```

or to be sure not to include directories:

```
find /var/log/ -maxdepth 1 -type f | grep -v 'btmp\|lastlog\|wtmp'
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also work.

```
find /var/log -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-extended -type f ! -regex '^.*/(btmp|wtmp|lastlog)$'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find /var/log ! \
      \( -name \[wb]tmp -o \
         -name lastlog  -o \
         -path '*g/*/*/*'  \
         -prune -o -type d \)
```

That will print only pathnames which are not of type directory, of basenames wtmp, btmp, or lastlog, or are any deeper than a single directory below a directory name ending with a g.

Comment: `find . -path "*g/*" -a ! -path "*g/*/*"`